# How to create a custom TextInput having facility to act as both secure field (with eye icon) and normal TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I wanted to develop a custom TextField which accepts a parameter for changing itself as a secure field with show and hide password facility. But I am stuck with an issue now. As the caller of my custom textfield will pass a State variable as parameter, i have to use @Binding here inside my class. But when i use binding, the text gets disappear while clicking the eye icon. Kindly correct me if my assumptions described above or coded below has any mistakes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BTextInput: View {
    @Binding var valueHolder : String
    var hint : String?
    @State var isSecure: Bool?
    @State var isTextHidden: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            if isSecure ?? false{

                if isTextHidden {
                    VStack{
                        SecureField("\(hint.optionalVal)" ,text : self.$valueHolder)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(.horizontal,4)
                            .padding(.trailing,28)

                        Rectangle().frame(height: 0.5)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }.overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isTextHidden.toggle()
                        }){
                            EyeImage(name: "eye")
                        }.padding(.top,2.5)
                        ,alignment: .topTrailing)
                }else{
                    VStack{
                        TextField("\(hint.optionalVal)" ,text : self.$valueHolder)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(.horizontal,4)
                            .padding(.trailing,28)

                        Rectangle().frame(height: 0.5)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }.overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isTextHidden.toggle()
                        }){
                            EyeImage(name: "eye.slash")
                        }.padding(.top,2.5)
                        ,alignment: .topTrailing)
                }
           }else{
                VStack{
                    TextField("\(hint.optionalVal)" ,text : self.$valueHolder)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.horizontal,4)

                    Rectangle().frame(height: 0.5)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
struct EyeImage: View {

    private var imageName: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.imageName = name
    }
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName : imageName)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}

struct BTextInput_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack{
            BTextInput(valueHolder: Binding.constant(""), hint: "Account")
            BTextInput(valueHolder: Binding.constant(""), hint: "Account", isSecure: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This code will work as expected if we change the '@Binding var valueHolder : String' as '@State var valueHolder : String'. But I need to keep it as a binding variable itself as this is a custom TextInput.

It will be appreciable if you can suggest any better approach to achieve the same.
(Also the mistakes in my code / better coding practises)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not take into account lost focus in visibility change, all works fine. I assume you confused by using constant binding in Preview, because binding, actually, is passive - it is state responsible for update. So to preview component dependent on binding it is needed a helper view having active state, like below:

```
struct BTextInput_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    struct TestSecureFieldSwitch: View {
        @State private var text = ""
        @State private var pass = ""
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                BTextInput(valueHolder: $text, hint: "Account")
                BTextInput(valueHolder: $pass, hint: "Password", isSecure: true)
            }
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        TestSecureFieldSwitch()
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: Shall i ask you one more doubt ? 
in the securefiled, if we type any thing and focus out from the component and then again if we try to type something on the securefiled, will it clear the previously typed values? Is that the default behavior of the SecureField ?

Comment: @prebeesh, not sure if I understood you correctly, but SecureField just presents string via binding, it does not reset/clear anything by itself. If there are characters in bound string variable (State or Published) then they shown in Text/Secure field.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot. I am unable to upvote answers yet in stackoverflow otherwise i would have definitely upvoted for your help.